# Looking analytically if one formula is better than another one

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, numerical-methods, error-propagation

I'm studying errors in functions on numerical methods. **On my notes**, I've written the Heron's Formula: Let $a\geq b\geq c$:$$A=\sqrt{p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)}\ \ ,$$ where $$p=\frac{a+b+c}{2}.$$

This formula suffers cancellation if $a \sim b+c$ on the factor $(p-a)$. Looking for a reformulation, we find that $$A=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{(a+(b+c))(c-(a-b))(c+(a-b))(a+(b-c))}.$$ **It's easy to show that this formula is better analytically than the other one if we're looking to avoid cancellation errors.**

How we show this? How can we see that the formula below is better than the above one? Thanks!

Comment: You said it's easy to show. What is the method you would use to show that?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг This is from my class notes.

Comment: What does "suffering cancellation" mean in the case of $(p-a)$, because it's in the numerator of whatever expression you have. Your class notes should be more clear on what this means. I think what you want is that there should be no denominator in your formula, right? Because otherwise I see  no difference between the expressions,

Comment: The formula has cancellation if $a\sim b+c$

Comment: Oh, I see. Is your error a constant or a proportional error to the quantity?

Comment: The alternative formula isn't free from numerical instability (which is the usual term for "cancellation error") either. What happens if $c \approx a \gg b$?

Comment: The error comes from the loss ofnsignificant figures from the cancellation when $a\sim b+c$ holds

Comment: @user21820 $a\geq b\geq c$

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг: The question is probably about numerical instability.. If $a \sim b+c$, then $a+b+c \sim 2a$ and hence their difference completely 'loses' the significant term.

Comment: @Relure: Sorry I didn't see that condition at the start of your question. Then it seems fine to me. You just have to track the error terms and see how they cancel.

Comment: Thank you, @user21820, but now my earlier question, namely are these error terms constants or proportional to the values they are arising from?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг: Usually we assume fixed-precision, which means errors are bounded by a fixed proportion of the actual value.

Comment: All right, now the problem should be easy. Thanks once again.